# NativeScript URL Handler Plugin trouble to make it working

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, deeplink

I am trying to use this plugin with Nativescript Angular.
I followed the tutorial [Nativescript Url Handler](https://github.com/speigg/nativescript-urlhandlertps://)

In my app.component.ts :

```
ngOnInit() {
    handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {
        console.log('Got the following appURL', appURL);
        alert(appURL);
    });
}
```

In android manifest :

```
<activity
android:name=".activities.Activity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And when I input to my Google Chrome navigator : http://example.com/ or http://www.example.com/ ,
it does not work. Any help, i would appreciate.

Comment: I don't think hitting URL on Chrome's address bar will open your app. It should be a link, when you click the link it would try to open your app. For example, even youtube - if you hit youtube.com it will still open it in Chrome browser. If you click a Youtube video link may be from Google search, then it would try to launch the app.

Comment: Also do not forget to try a clean build.

Comment: You were right @Manoj great thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think hitting URL on Chrome's address bar will open your app. It should be a link, when you click the link it would try to open your app.

For example, even YouTube - if you hit youtube.com it will still open it in Chrome browser. If you click a Youtube video link may be from a Google search, then it would try to launch the app.

*Also do not forget to try a clean build.*